# What does this line from "Blood and Chocolate" mean?

Tags: blood-and-chocolate

There are few lines or sentences in this book that I don't get (because I'm not English). What does this mean?

> Orlando waved them quiet. "The Law is specific in this matter, Rafael. Bone and flesh, flesh and bone, a man takes time to grow them. Two-five-two number the moons that it takes for a man to know them. Till then he is not the match of a man, and a man is not bound to match him."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Orlando is giving the requirement to be an adult, namely that an individual must be 252 months ("two-five-two moons") old. As we can easily calculate:

> "That's twenty-one years for you slow students," Bucky pointed out.

Comment: Heh.  Except, of course, that since a lunar (synodic) month is almost a day shorter than an average calendar month, 252 synodic periods ends up being almost 8 synodic periods short of 21 years...

Comment: These guys are similar to werewolves, so I guess they count the number of full moons quite precisely @DavidW

Comment: Assumig that the average tme between lunations is about 29.530587981 days, 252 moons would equal about 7,441.7079 days, or about 20.374285 Julian calendar years, whcih is close enough.

Comment: Hi @Reika does my response answer your question, or is there some further explanation I can give?

Comment: @Clara Diaz Sanchez Hi! Now I get it, thanks for your useful answer! :) If I still have a question about more parts of the book, can I ask you? :D

Comment: Of course! Post the question, and I or anybody else will be happy to try to answer it. Meanwhile, if you are happy with my answer, can you click the green tick to accept it? That way people will know that the question is answered. Thanks.

Comment: It's OK :) Thank you for your help! :)